# Leave blank combined with IF data entry

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like the following scenario resolved if possible. I have the following formula;

```
=if(B3>C3,"3",if(B3<C3,"0",if(B3=C3,"1")))
```

So that the result of football matches enters either `3`, `1` or `0` points into B4.

I'm trying to have it so that if no data is entered into B3 or C3, B4 is blank. The variants I've tried so far have come up fruitless.

Finally, I'm trying to use conditional formatting to have the whole area turn green, yellow or red dependent on the result but this isn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a neater way but the following should suit:

```
 =if(and(B3="",C3=""),"",if(B3>C3,"3",if(B3<C3,"0",if(B3=C3,"1"))))
```